# Issues rendering a gradient background in chrome?

Tags: html, css

```
body
{
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #787878 100%);
}
```

I'm getting this kind of [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnSq7.jpg) when I want a true gradient, of course.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make this work properly, you need:

```
body, html {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #787878 100%);
  margin:0;
  height:100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/3rb2L/2/

```
body
{
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7); 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height:200px;
}
```

`height:200px` is just for example and clear viewing purpose.

Can be used as: http://jsfiddle.net/3rb2L/4/

```
html{
  min-height:100%;
}
body
{
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7); 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: So what happens when the content is more than 200px high?